# What am I? I would look strange on your body

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I would look strange on your body,
>
> but not on your phone.
>
> You appreciate me most
>
> when you're not home.
>
> There's not enough clues,
>
> so let's make this a twofer...
>
> I watch what you do,
>
> and I have no future.
>
> **What am I?**

---

**Edit History:** Started with four lines written in third-person. It was too vague so I made small edits and adjusted the title to match. It was too open-ended so I added a second half with more clues. Also added the "wordplay" tag.

Comment: Anyone know when/why the OP's account was deleted? It looks like we're never going to know the answer to this now, and that's a darn shame.

Answer (score 17):

I think it should be

> Camera

I would look strange on your body,

> Picture from CCTV is always look strange or it would be weird if you wore a camera. (credit to [rm-vanda](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4616/rm-vanda))

but not on your phone.

> Picture from Mobile is almost look good.

You appreciate me most
when you're not home.

> CCTV camera safe when we are not at home.

**Updated:**

I watch what you do,

> Camera watch everything.

and I have no future.

> Camera see only present moment.

Comment: post hint this seems more likely

Comment: CCTV / Cameras have no future to look at (only what has happened) and they watch what you do when they're on. makes sense to me yes

Comment: Good thought, I originally thought this but with the popularity of GoPros on people's heads I thought past it. It also works with the edit hints. Pretty sure this is the answer :)

Comment: @CJ1992 I have given answer before hint so might be not correct answer

Comment: I think it would "look strange on your body" because it would be weird if you wore a camera.

Comment: Drats! I thought of this right after I saw the riddle, but I was late to the punch by 10 hours.

Answer (score 5):

is it

> key

I would look strange on your body,

> indeed

but not on your phone.

> key from keypad

You appreciate me most

when you're not home.

> I don't know what I will do, if I am not at home AND I don't have the key

Comment: Nice duality of "it" on a phone vs home.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Antenna?

I would look strange on your body,

> Humans don't have organic or mechanical antennas

but not on your phone.

> Older phones have them more, more recently.

You appreciate me most
when you're not home.

> Because without it, we need wifi, which is harder to find away from home.

Comment: Well, modern phones also have them. They're just more hidden.

Comment: You know that wifi requires an antenna too, do you?

Comment: People use WiFi at home too.

Comment: Antenna on body: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Harbisson

Answer (score 5):

Are you a:

> Clock

I would look strange on your body,

> Flavor Flav looked strange wearing a clock

but not on your phone.

> Your phone has a clock app

You appreciate me most when you're not home.

> You look at the clock more while at work waiting to go home

There's not enough clues, so let's make this a twofer...
I watch what you do,

> A clock has a face, watching you (potentially a play on "watch")

and I have no future.

> A clock only knows "now"

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> Lock?

They don't exactly make great clothes but her phone and home use one to

> Protect their contents

Comment: Great guess, but no. Would it look strange on her? I'm sure lots of things would, but there's one answer in particular that I think works better than the rest.

Comment: @GoogleFail While your intention may be aimed at a specific answer, A lock on a body is pretty strange and suffices the restrictions you've put in the riddle.

Comment: @humblerookie, I'm new at this and kind of jumping in the deep end here, but yeah, I see now that I could have done better. For some reason I thought you guys would get it instantly, but I guess I can't assume other people think the way I do. I just added a hint which you can treat like the second half of the riddle if you like...or just be happy with your answer to the original since it is pretty good!

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> A Photo

Would look strange on someones body, But not on a phone.

> You appreciate a photo most when away from the subject in the photo

Comment: This also is an appropriate answer given the additional clues.

Answer (score 4):

This probably doesn't work very well with the additional clues, but works really well with the original ones.

What am I?

> A case

I would look strange on your body,

> People don't wear cases, and  trying to wear a phone case would certainly look weird.

But not on your phone.

> Phones commonly have cases, often decorative ones.

You appreciate me most when you're not home.

> People are much more likely to drop and damage phones when out and about (thus needing a protective case), while protective cases are often just annoying at home.

Let's make this a twofer...

> Phone cases often come in two separate parts.

I have no future.

> Phone cases will be replaced whenever you get a new phone, or when they are damaged, and may not last long.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought about answering but, since you already answered I'll just upvote instead.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> An answering machine

Alice obviously can't have one on herself, but her phone can because

> The whole point of it is to reply on behalf of someone. You never mentioned whether the phone is a mobile or a wired one.

You appreciate me most when you're not home

> One needs an answering machine the most when they are away from their phone at home.

Comment: I think you just nailed it. Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Good first answer!

Comment: I really like this answer, nice job! But in all honesty, who uses these things nowadays?

Answer (score 3):

This will probably not be what you were searching for but you never know.
Are you:

> Free Wifi?

I would look strange on your body,

> This would be a weird Tattoo!

but not on your phone.

> Wifi on the phone is normal

You appreciate me most when you're not home.

> Free wifi is always a nice thing so you won't have to use mobile data.

Comment: Watch what you do works. Have no future... also works with the advent of atadGGG.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> incognito

I would look strange on your body,

> I think this reffers to the incognito hat and glass symbol

but not on your phone.

> Phone browser has incognito mode

You appreciate me most, when you're not home.

> Yes. i do, because in incognito mod non of your search history and cookies are saved. :P

I watch what you do,

> Because you are in my phones browser, you see what i do with phone browser.

and I have no future.

> The history will not be saved. so no history and future.

Comment: while it does satisfy most, It seems to be a bit vague on the, "watch what you do front"

Comment: Well, yrotsih hcraes is still saved.

Answer (score 2):

Are you a

> map?

You appreciate me most when you're not home.

> If she got lost she'd want to find her way home.

Comment: Prison Break much? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> wallpaper?

Alice would look very strange walking around with that on her, but her phone

> has one as a background

and Alice appreciates it the stuff at home when she's not there because

> absence makes the heart grow fonder. Alice just really loves wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> directions?

Since this is a bit of an abstract noun, I'm not even sure **how** it would appear on Alice.

On her phone this is a perfectly normal thing to see to help her

> find out where she is and where to go

And this is obviously most away from home since

> we'd hope Alice knows where she is when she's at home!

Answer (score 1):

Is it ?

> a hat

I would look strange on your body,

> depends on the type of hat and person <-- see twofer part

but not on your phone.

> A Help Authoring Tool or HAT is a software program used by technical writers to create online help systems  <-- Thus software

You appreciate me most
when you're not home.

> When it's sunny outside

There's not enough clues,
so let's make this a twofer...

> google results returned a twofer hat https://nl.pinterest.com/pin/100275529172649034/?lp=true

I watch what you do,
and I have no future.

> If you wear it it will be with you(watch you?), And it's an object so it doesn't realy have a future.

What am I?

> a hat

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a

> Watch

It has no future and it is a twofer
You appreciate it the most when you're not home.

This is my first attempt too on SE. :)

Answer (score 0):

> You are a phone charger!
>  I don't think I need to clarify any more if you are one.

Answer (score 0):

I was about to post this as a joke in the comments until I realized it might be the actual answer. (Well, maybe. I'm still mostly leaning towards humorous here). I believe it could be:

> Google

I would look strange on your body, but not on your phone.

> anrdoid looks great on phones

You appreciate me most when you're not home.

> Okay google, open maps and get directions to home. Or "Call me an uber".

I watch what you do,

> Google

and I have no future.

> I leave this one to the imagination of the reader.